# Different Hudson folders for wars and jobs

Tags: hudson

Is there any way to have the **war files** of **Hudson** in an **different directory** or drive that the **job files**.

We want to have all executables in c:\programme\hudson and all jobs in f:\data\hudson.

I've alredy played around with  in hudson.xml. But this redirects not only the job directory but copies also the whole war directory to the new destination folder.

Is there any way to configure Hudson (on a *windows server*) to have a separation of the executable and the data/job directories?

Answer (score 1):

Seting [HUDSON_HOME](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Administering+Hudson) to f:\data\hudson should do the trick

Comment: I've done that already as I've mentioned. This copies with some magic a war, a jobs, a plugins and a user directory to the target directory from the Hudson_home settings (ie. f:\data\hudson). 
I am confused because I've belived all file from war directoy kept on the old drive but the same number of files in in the new war directory like in the original directory. 
I don't understand the reason why the war file are all copied to the new directory.

Comment: By the way: I've tested it in two ways. First I've changed the HUDSON_HOME value to a directory on the same drive as the installtion. This works fine. All files are copied to the new and empty directory after the Hudson server has been restarted. And you can access the Hudson web site :-) 
In the second environment I've done the same but redirected the HUDSON_HOME value to a different drive than the installation. In this scenery the service starts without any errors but no files will be copied to the target directory. And the Hudson web site is not accessable anymore (web page can't be found)

Comment: @user438935 how are you running hudson, i.e. which servlet container are you using? I've never seen the hudson WAR file in HUDSON_HOME.

For the different directory: Could it be that this was a permission issue?

Comment: Not a war file but a war directory with 1098 files. Hudson is installed on an Windows Server and on an Windows XP without any servlet conatainer so far as I know because it was installed by "-DHUDSON_HOME=c:\programme\Hudson -jar hudson.war" as Service
And its no permission problem. I've have checked that already.

Comment: You installed it as an standalone application. In this case it uses the integrated Winstone engine. If you want a little bit more flexibility you might consider to deploy it to a app server.

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem has not an easy solution. Besides deploying to an app server, I can come up with two options.

1. Configure the workspace explicitly in every job to point to F:\data\hudson
2. create a file system link from c:\programme\hudson\jobs to f:\data\hudson. I have never used it. So have fun reading through the following links. [hard links and junctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364215%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), [symbolic links](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365680%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but I run hudson simply via `java -jar`, and then I can specify freely where the hudson war is.  It seems the war unpacks into HUDSON_HOME when starting up, but I still have a separate directory where I keep the wars and download upgrades, and I can just change the shortcut when I want to run a newer war.

Answer (score 0):

We run Hudson on a Windows server and use Tomcat as our container.

In this setup, you can set HUDSON_HOME to whatever you want, which holds the job configuration, and then the HUDSON.WAR file lives in `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps.`